# DynamoDB add trigger before insert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is there any way we can create a trigger before an insert into DynamoDB?

I have a scenario where I do not know the partition key and I was considering resolving it in the trigger (which is a regular lambda function).

This is because I needed a place where these operations would be atomic and trigger looked like a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of before insert trigger functionality on DynamoDB. However, for transactional use cases, DynamoDB support Transactions, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html for more information.